# New JSS app will not start: GraphQL requests to Dictionary and Layout services are not supported in disconnected mode

Tags: jss, graphql, react

I'm following along with Discover Sitecore's "Build Your First JSS App" video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNQGsr9_34A) and was only 2:10 in when I ran into my first issue.
All I've done so far was install jss globally using the command
`npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli`
and then I created a new jss app using this command
`npm init sitecore-jss react`
After `cd` to the new directory, I attempted to execute the command `jss start` when I got the errors indicated.

```
> npm run start --

> sitecore-jss-app@20.0.1 start
> cross-env-shell JSS_MODE=disconnected "npm-run-all --serial bootstrap --parallel start:react start:proxy start:watch-components"


> sitecore-jss-app@20.0.1 bootstrap
> cross-env-shell FETCH_WITH=GraphQL "node scripts/bootstrap.js"

C:\Projects\jss-react\scripts\bootstrap.js:15
  throw new Error(
  ^

Error: GraphQL requests to Dictionary and Layout services are not supported in disconnected mode.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\jss-react\scripts\bootstrap.js:15:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node scripts\bootstrap.js ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Projects\jss-react\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Projects\jss-react\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Projects\jss-react\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Projects\jss-react\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn node scripts\\bootstrap.js',
  path: 'node scripts\\bootstrap.js',
  spawnargs: []
}
ERROR: "bootstrap" exited with 1.
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm-run-all --serial bootstrap --parallel start:react start:proxy start:watch-components ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Projects\jss-react\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Projects\jss-react\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Projects\jss-react\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Projects\jss-react\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm-run-all --serial bootstrap --parallel start:react start:proxy start:watch-components',
  path: 'npm-run-all --serial bootstrap --parallel start:react start:proxy start:watch-components',
  spawnargs: []
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run this command `npm init sitecore-jss react` it ask some option one of them is `How would you like to fetch Layout and Dictionary data?` it have two types (`GraphQL and Rest`) as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Please select `Rest` then it will start working because i think `GraphQL` doesn't supports in `disconnected mode`.

I tried it and it's started working, please see below screenshot

[image]

Comment: This did resolve the error so I will mark this as the answer, thank you. Do you have any info on how I would switch to connected mode with GraphQL?

Comment: Switching to GraphQL is now as simple as setting FETCH_WITH environment variable (used to be changing dictionary-service-factory.js and layout-service-factory.js). To switching to connected mode you just have to run `jss setup` and then `jss start:connected`. [Switch between REST and GraphQL](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/switch-between-rest-and-graphql-in-next-js-jss-apps.html)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of executing `npm init sitecore-jss react` we can update the **FETCH_WITH** parameter in **.env** file because in Next.js **Dictionary** and **Layout** service factory have made an easy way to switch from disconnected to connected mode.

After that, when you will run `jss start`, your jss site will be up and running locally in disconnected mode.

Comment: Yes, this switching is definitely a better way than re-initializing a project